# Upload a Rails project without gems like NodeJS project without modules

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, ruby

I am a little confused about the project upload. I have developed some Ruby on Rails project and want to upload it to google drive(own purposes). However, I am confused regarding the upload step. If you are familiar with NodeJS, we don't upload node_modules into our repository, since once we clone the repository we can issue `npm install`, and it will install all the modules. Is there similar thing in Rails? Also, in NodeJS we have package.json file where we can include commands to run inside 'script', such as

```
"scripts": {
    "devStart": "nodemon server.js"
  }
```

Is there a similar thing in Ruby on Rails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Rails usually use [bundler](https://bundler.io).

All gems are in `Gemfile`.

When you run `bundle` it generates `Gemfile.lock`. `Gemfile.lock` contains all versions and dependecies of project. So when other user will run `bundle`, he will get all the neccessary versions of gems.

You can also use `Procfile` with scripts for your servers like in Node.js.